# Constant pointer variables in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262)

I know two variations of pointer variables in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

Say I have

```
mystruct{
    int num;
}
```

Variation 1:

`const mystruct* m1;` means the member variables in m1 can not be altered, for instance, `m1->num = 2` would produce an error.

Variation 2:

`mystruct *const m2 = m1;` means once m2 is set to point to m1, an error would be produced if you subsequently set `m2 =m3`.

However, there seems to be a third variation, that I am not certain the property of:

Variation 3:

```
mystruct const * m3;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Note that in version 1 the meaning is that members of the pointer object cannot be changed **using that m1 pointer**, not that they cannot be changed in general. In other words nothing is said about the object being pointed to is constant... the word const is still **relative to the pointer**, with the meaning of "can't be used for writing".

Comment: Voting to close since this is an exact duplicate save for the use of `mystruct` instead of `int`. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variant 3 is exactly the same as variant 1. The `const` applies to whatever is to the **left** of it. If there is nothing (first variant), it applies to the thing that is **right** of it. Also, you're missing one variation.

```
const int* pi1; // varyable pointer to constant int
int const* pi2; // again - varyable pointer to constant int
int* const pi3; // constant pointer to varyable int
// you're missign the next
int const * const pi4; // constant pointer to constant int
```

---

I personally prefer the second version to the first, as that is what the compiler parses and when you read the type from right to left, it is clearer. :) Also, that's what I did in the comments - intuitive, isn't it?

Oh, yeah, all of the above also applies to `volatile`. Together they're counted as `cv-qualifiers` (`cv` = `const volatile`).

And as a last point, for future references: There's always [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org). As long as you don't mix in C++ types, you can find out the meaning of potentially any declaration. **Edit**: Interestingly enough, it chokes on `int const i;`. I think I'll need to research if the variable ordering of cv-qualifiers was introduced in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Declarations in C++ consist of two parts:

> decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list ;

The decl-specifier-seq is a sequence of keywords, such as `volatile`, `const`, `mutable` `typedef` etc... and a type. The order of these specifiers doesn't matter, so you can write:

```
int typedef unsigned A;
int const B = 1;
```

and they are the same as

```
typedef unsigned int A;
const int B = 1;
```

init-declarator-list is the comma separated sequence of entities you declare. Each of these entities gets the type of the decl-specifier-seq with some modifiers applied to it:

```
int typedef *A, B[10], *const C;
```

Here A gets the type 'pointer to int', B is an array of ints and C is a constant pointer to int.

As you see in your case:

```
mystruct const *m2 = m1;
```

the `const` is a part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, so it modifies `mystruct` to be const, not the pointer itself.